# Can I adopt a pug into a household with two German shepherds?

Tags: dogs, behavior, german-shepherd

My family and I are the proud owner of our two beautiful angels, Daisy(8 years) and Dalmi(5 years). Both of them are German shepherds. Dalmi is Daisy's daughter. They are friendly with people and especially with kids but they are ferocious to cats and the people who are scared of them. They have not bitten anyone yet though. Now, my mother and sister wants to adopt a pug, but some people are saying not to include a pug into a household with two German shepherds.

Do German shepherds not like pugs? Am I able to bring a pug into our family.

Comment: No one can say with certainty whether a dog of one breed will like a dog of another breed. It depends on the personalities of the individual dogs.

Comment: Jay's edit changes this question from an opinion based question that was out of scope, to an interaction question that can be answered.

Comment: Just to give you a possible reason why people might have formed that opinion, German Shepherds make for good guard dogs not because they're big and brave and mean but because they're often naturally anxious and suspicious/afraid of things. Pair a stereotypical anxious German Shepherd with a flat-faced dog, which robs it of many canine communication channels, and you can see why it would happen. That doesn't mean it has to, just that it might have happened often enough for people to form said opinion

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

There isn't any breed that isn't able to get along with any other breed. For example, there's no rule that says pugs cannot get along with shepherds.

The real issue is one of temperament, as @James Jenkins suggested, and of trainer skill level, and a question of whether the dog is a good match for its owner and family. For example, a dog with extremely high energy levels is a terrible match for a very laid back family that is lazy and does not want to go on walks.

With three dogs, it's faster for things to go from calm to chaos, and identifying those signals and knowing the dogs is where trainer skill comes in.

It's best to give everyone a trial run (not inside any dog's territory) and carefully observe if the dogs will get along and if they are a good match for one another.